# RxJava Chaining two Completables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am very new to RxJava and have a problem. I try to chain two Completables. So the scenario is to update some Category Objects and afterwards update the UI. Both tasks will be executed within a Completable. I chained those two with the andThen operator but sometimes the UI Completable does not get executed and i dont get any error.

```
        Disposable d = FilterController.getInstance().updateChosenCategoriesCompletable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .andThen(FilterController.getInstance().updateChosenCategoriesInterfaceCompletable())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d("MultiselectDialog", "Categories Update Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    ExceptionHandler.saveException(e, null, null);
                    Log.d("MultiselectDialog", "error");
                }
            });
```

I am not sure but i think this is caused by executing the first Completable on the IO Thread. Is this forbidden when i try to chain two Completables? The weird thing about it is that the second Completable does not get execute sometimes (1 out of 10 Times for example). When i insert a delay or do everything on the Main Thread then everything works. I just want to know if its forbidden to chain two Completables with two different threads.

Thanks for your help in advance!

/edit

The updateChosenCategoriesCompletable() is using this Completable:

```
public Completable setChosenCategoryCompletable(final ArrayList<CategoryHolder> category, final boolean callFilterOptionsChanged) {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            try {
                Log.d("Workflow", "setChosenCategoryCompletable " + category.size());
                Log.d("Workflow", "setChosenCategoryCompletable " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                mChosenCategories = category;

                if (callFilterOptionsChanged) {
                    mFilterOptionsChangedListener.filterOptionsChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Workflow", "error set");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and the updateChosenCategoriesCompletable() is using this Completable

```
    public Completable updateCategoryLabelTextCompletable(final ArrayList<CategoryHolder> categories) {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            Log.d("Workflow", "updateCategoryLabelTextCompletable " + categories.size());
            Log.d("Workflow", "updateCategoryLabelTextCompletable " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            TextView selectedValue = mLabels.get(mActivity.getString(R.string.CATEGORY));
            ImageView categoryIcon = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
            if(categories.size() > 1) {
                selectedValue.setText(String.valueOf(categories.size()));
                categoryIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if(categories.isEmpty()) {
                selectedValue.setText(mActivity.getString(R.string.CATEGORY_EMPTY));
                categoryIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                selectedValue.setText(categories.get(0).getCategory());

                // Set category image if only one category is selected
                categoryIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String categoryImage = categories.get(0).getCategoryImage();
                if(!categoryImage.isEmpty()){

                    int imageResource = mActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(categoryImage, "drawable", mActivity.getPackageName());

                    Drawable image = null;

                    // getDrawable(int) is deprecated since API 21
                    try {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            image = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource, null);
                        } else {
                            image = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(image != null){
                        categoryIcon.setImageDrawable(image);
                    }
                }else {
                    categoryIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is it mandatory to use fromCallable instead?

This is the method that updates the button i mentioned:

```
    public void setResultButtonText(final String text, final boolean buttonEnabled) {

    if(mShowResultsButton != null) {

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mShowResultsButton.setText(text);
                    mShowResultsButton.setEnabled(buttonEnabled);
                    if (buttonEnabled) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            mShowResultsButton.setBackground(mActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple));
                        } else {
                            mShowResultsButton.setBackground(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            mShowResultsButton.setBackground(mActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple_grey));
                        } else {
                            mShowResultsButton.setBackground(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple_grey));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Filterinterface", "ERROR");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can combine `Completable`s running on different threads on their own, RxJava will work out the proper concurrent handling of them. `andThen` requires the first `Completable` to complete normally, only then will it subscribe to the second `Completable`. The indication that delay makes things work could mean there is something wrong in `updateChosenCategoriesCompletable()` or `updateChosenCategoriesInterfaceCompletable()`. For example, they start executing immediately and return a hot `Completable` instead of starting their work when subscribed to. Please provide their implementation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've edited my post.

Comment: Is there a requirement `mFilterOptionsChangedListener.filterOptionsChanged();` is run on the main thread? Currently it runs on the `io` thread because of `setChosenCategoryCompletable`

Comment: I would try to do it the way it's recommended since RxJava2 and use ```Completable.create{ //do your things here }```

Comment: And for the deprecation thing there is : ```ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);```

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's `create`, `fromAction` or `fromCallable`. The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Just saying that i'ts recommended...

Comment: And in order to find the answer for this, please add a ```do{}``` after each Completable and post the logs from all events...

Comment: Given it's an action to be performed, I would have recommended `fromAction` anyway. `create` is for [bridging with other traditionally async sources](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#create-io.reactivex.CompletableOnSubscribe-) (listener callbacks), it's just an effect it can work for synchronous actions.

Comment: The architecture is a bit confusing. I figured out that filterOptionsChanged() triggers our realm database to update on the current filter options. As a result of the current amount of items from the database a button (which should show the list of the items) gets updated with the size of items. This of course should happen on the UI Thread.

But shouldn't i get a Throwable in onError? Or am i wrong?

Comment: I'd think so. Maybe your logging is turned off or filtering out System.err or debug messages?

Comment: Or is the Error getting lost because i am invoking runOnUiThread() method on the IO Thread? I dont get any Exceptions even when i chose "no filters" in Logcat in Android Studio.